# Tools to compare changes in TFS 2005 Branches

Tags: tfs

Are there any Tools to compare the differences between branches in TFS 2005?. OR How do I see Tree Difference Tab in TFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS Power tools will let you compare two branches. After you install it right click and compare on a folder. Put in the branch name to compare it with and it will show the Tree Difference Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest from each branch and then use [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) (or any diff'ing tool of your choice) to diff the source locally.

Comment: Can thi sbe used with Visual studio Team Systems  2005?.

Comment: Sure -- it's a standalone tool.

Comment: That said, it will be much much slower.  The power tool (which is built directly into VS 2008) compares hash values which are already stored on the server; KDiff3 and similar tools must actually read the full contents from disk.